# Installing new version of component removes menu link from administrator menu

Tags: joomla, menu

I made a component, where user can generate view with a link to it (backend). Link is generated in administrator menu. After I install same component again, generated links are removed. Why is that, how can I prevent that ?

Answer (score 0):

did you change something in the component? (names, class names, etc?)

If not, the component should be normally upgraded (check if install script is OK: administrator/components/com_your_component/install/script.php - compare it with other components).

If yes, there can be problem in database (duplicity, etc.). It can happen, that if you develope a component and you are trying to install it again and on the site previous version is installed with other names, this then ends with missing menu items (links) in administration.

Backup your data and try to remove the component from the system completely (see: http://www.phoca.cz/phocagallery/16-joomla/joomla/650-removing-component-from-joomla-system-manually ) include its folders.

And then try to install it again.

If the script.php is OK, and no changes were made in the component (name changing), then reinstallation should only upgrade the component. Upgrade then means, that links will not be removed.

You can try to enable the links manually if they are unpublished (see the link above, this solve the problem on your site but does not solve the problems with your component)

Jan

Comment: Hey Jan, actually I'm installing same version on it. But there's no such folder like /install, can this be the reason ?

Comment: Hi, depends on which Joomla! version you are using. If Joomla! 3 then you should have **install** folder and **script.php** indside it. If Joomla! 2.5 then your install file can be located in root of the component, called **install.your_component.php**. I will recommend to backup the data, remove the component from your Joomla! manually and completely (include the deleting of component's folder) and try to install it newly.